# Sending function without params causing unset variable error

Tags: jquery

Apoligies for my basic understanding of jQuery. I am trying to write a function that can have values set by the user or left blank, set themselves. It looks like this:

```
// Calendar
function eventCalendar(yearSet, monthSet) { 

    // Get current date
    var date = new Date();

    // Check to see if variables were set in function

    // Year
    if ((yearSet.length > 0)) {
            var year = yearSet;
        } else {
            var year  = date.getFullYear();
        }

    // Month
    if ((monthSet.length > 0)) {
            var month = monthSet;
        } else {
            var month = date.getMonth();
        }

    console.log(month + ', ' + year);   
}
```

However when the function is called without variables, console sends me the error:

> 'yearSet is undefined'

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(yearSet && yearSet.length) {
   //..
}
```

You can simplify your method like this.

```
function eventCalendar(yearSet, monthSet) { 
  var date = new Date();
  //if yearSet is present it will get that or else from new Date
  var year = yearSet || date.getFullYear();
  //if monthSet is present it will get that or else from new Date
  var month = monthSet || date.getMonth();

  console.log(month + ', ' + year);   
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, however I am confused about how those 'or' operators are working.

Does it just ignore the first variable in the or statement if it is undefined?.. So if I changed it to var year = date.getFullYear() || yearSet; it would set it to the date.getFullYear and ignore the user variable, even if it was defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the truthy or falsey nature of of the parameters rather than checking if they are undefined explicitly:

```
function eventCalendar(yearSet, monthSet) { 
  var date = new Date();
  var year = yearSet && yearSet.length ? yearSet : date.getFullYear();
  var month = monthSet && monthSet.length ? monthSet : date.getMonth();
  console.log(month + ', ' + year);   
}
```

FYI your current error was caused by attempting to access a property (`length`) of an `undefined` variable (`year`). I'd suggest having a Google about the truthiness and falsiness in JavaScript IMO it's a really useful feature of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it to `undefined` or `null` instead of checking the length

Answer (score 0):

Check if variable is undefined with this code:

```
if(typeof(variable) === 'undefined') {
    // var is undefined
}
```

Your code will throw error because when you use `.length` you assume that given variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that " " is considered a valid value for a field to contain.  You want to do something a little more sexy:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function eventCalendar (y,m) {
  var date = new Date(); 
  y=(isNumber(y) ? y : date.getFullYear(); 
  m=(isNumber(m) ? m : date.getMonth(); 
  console.log(m + " " + y);
}
```

untested, but it should do what you want.